# How to login to test account (phone number +99966xxxx) without manual codes in telethon

Tags: telegram, telethon

I use telethon to test my telegram bot. I use the test server 2. I need an extra account to test `client1 <-> bot <-> client2` interaction.

There are free accounts with phone numbers `99966Yxxxx` and passwords equal to `YYYYY`, where `Y` is in [1, 2] according to https://core.telegram.org/api/auth#test-accounts

I cannot make the default example https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/developing/test-servers.html to work with such test account:

```
client = telethon.TelegramClient(None, api_id, api_hash, loop=event_loop)
seed = "4312"
phone = f'+999662{seed}'
client.session.set_dc(2, '149.154.167.40', 80)
client.start(phone=phone, code_callback=lambda:'22222')
```

I receive `telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.PhoneNumberUnoccupiedError: The phone number is not yet being used (caused by SignInRequest)` error on the last command.

I tried `client.sign_in(phone=phone, code='22222')`,

I tried `443` port instead of `80`.

Nothing works.

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates you need to sign up with that phone number first. You should be able to use [`SignUpRequest`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/auth/sign_up.html) in v1 to sign create the account:

```
from telethon import functions, types

async def main():
    token = await client.send_code_request(phone)
    result = client(functions.auth.SignUpRequest(
        phone_number=phone,
        phone_code_hash=token.phone_code_hash,
        first_name='name',
        last_name=''
    ))
```